# How to add a specific characters at the end of the words only in the first column?

Tags: awk, sed

I need to manipulate the file this way:

**File In -**

```
1 34566 34765 

2 45678 45789

3 34567 34799

X 67895 66900

Y 34567 34890
```

**file out**

```
1_M 34566 34765

2_M 45678 45789

3_M 34567 34799

X_M 67895 66900

Y_M 34567 34890
```

Thanks,

Comment: Read [ask] then do as required to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat data 
1 34566 34765 
2 45678 45789
3 34567 34799
X 67895 66900
Y 34567 34890
```

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $1 "_M",$2,$3}' data 
1_M 34566 34765
2_M 45678 45789
3_M 34567 34799
X_M 67895 66900
Y_M 34567 34890
```

using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^\S*/&_M/' data 
1_M 34566 34765 
2_M 45678 45789
3_M 34567 34799
X_M 67895 66900
Y_M 34567 34890
```

Explanation:

1. `awk '{print $1 "_M",$2,$3}' data` prints out the 1st field
   concatenated with "_M" followed by 2nd field and then 3rd field.
   Note that concatenation operator in `awk` is a space.

As for the `sed` command:

1. `sed 's/^\S*/&_M/' data` runs the substitute(`s` command) to
   substitute
2. `^\S*` => `\s` means white-space characters, `\S` means non
   whitespace characters, `*` means 0 or more. `^` is an anchor to
   ensure matching starts from line beginning.
3. `&` in sed means the matched string
4. Therefore in short we substitute `^\S*` with `^\S*_M`.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Could you please give some explanation. I went through SED tutorial to work this out but couldn't. If there is some explanation it would help.